# change directory as another user

Tags: bash, scripts

I am trying to access a directory as another user and read some information from that directory. I am not able to change directory.

Here is my shell script.

```
sudo -u $target_user -i <<'EOF'
cd /local/sites/repo
branch_name=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
echo $branch_name
EOF
```

Comment: So - what happens, exactly? Where is the directory `target_dir` located - remember that `sudo -i` will attempt to change to `$target_user`'s home directory

Comment: @steeldriver . Target_dir is present in /local/sites/ I have updated the question.

Comment: So what is the error? is the directory accessible to the user? what is the output of `sudo -u $target_user ls -ld /local/sites/repo`?

Comment: @steeldriver this is the output 

drwxrwxr-x 9 xxxx xxxxx 4096 Feb 13 16:47 /local/sites/repo

Comment: @steeldriver the error i get is not a git repository. But that location has a git repo


fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: So how do you know *specifically* that's because you are "not able to change directory"? Have you replaced the `branch_name=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)` with a `pwd` command?

Comment: @steeldriver yes . I did it printed /home/xxxxx. my target user's home directory

Comment: Does `$target_user` have some kind of restricted login shell (such as `rbash`)? Check with `getent passwd $target_user`

Comment: @steeldriver no.